# How can I get Taxonomy Images to work with 'orderby' argument?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, taxonomy

I'm using the Taxonomy Images plugin and am trying to sort the taxonomy but Taxonomy Images isn't playing nice. This works:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'work_cat', $args );
```

but this doesn't:

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', $args );
```

Any ideas? Here's the full query:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'work_cat',
        'orderby'      => 'id',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
    );

    $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', $args );

    $i = 0;
    $len = count($categories);
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    ?>
        <div class="fourcol <?php if ($i == 0): ?> first<?php elseif ($i == $len - 1): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'work_cat'); ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'full' ); ?></a>
        <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'work_cat'); ?>">See More &raquo;</a></div>

    <?php $i++;
    }
?>
```

Original post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-taxonomy-images-doesnt-adhere-to-orderby-argument

Comment: 1st: What is `apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', $args )` supposed to do? 2nd: Please don't cross post. Solve the question **in one OR another place**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: within $args, leave 'taxonomy' where it is and put the remaining three arguments in a 'term_args' sub-array.

Based on the documentation, it appears that the filter passes arguments to get_terms() through a 'term_args' sub-array. Your $args array is mixing filter arguments and get_terms() arguments at the same level, and it looks like that isn't supposed to work.

I have not tested this, but it's worth a shot.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/

G'luck!

E.

Comment: That did the trick—and thanks for pointing out the term_args in their documentation—I missed that (didn't know to look for it)! Cheers Erik.